# SOLR 8 as a service on Windows 7 using NSSM

Tags: windows, solr, nssm

I am trying to install SOLR 8 as a service on Windows 7 using NSSM. I keep getting the error saying:

> Windows could not start the service on Local Computer. There service
>   did not return an error. This could be an internal Windows error on
>   internal service error.

I had previously successfully done this for SOLR 7. Any suggestions?

Comment: I had the same problem, but it was just a path error  to the cmd file. Check your windows event log if you can find more details there

Answer (score 0):

Try checking windows event viewer for related errors which will give you more info about error. My guess would be username/password issue

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the things that cause this problem is the JAVA_HOME in the environment variables is not set correctly.
So make sure the JAVA_HOME is set in the **System Variables** and not in the account variables.